# Disable user interaction on one UIView as the other UIView is swiped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Before any starts, I understand `yourView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` is an option, but let me explain first the circumstance.

I have these 2 `UIView` objects, `stoneOne` and `stoneTwo`.  I have 4 `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` objects attached to them for up, down, left and right.  Imagine swiping these 'stones' around a 5x5 grid.

What I don't want is to be able to swipe both at the same time.

Currently, that bug is still an issue.  I'll show you a method called `swipeLeft:` which represents the layout for all swipe directions.

```
    - (IBAction)swipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
        _oldMove1 = _move1;
        _oldMove2 = _move2;
        if (recognizer.view == _oneStone
               && recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
            _twoStone.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            _oneStone = recognizer.view;
            [self moveOne:CGPointMake(-1, 0) withView:_oneStone];
            self.move1++;
            // 'causeADelay:' runs _twoStone.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            [self performSelector:@selector(causeADelay:) withObject:_twoStone afterDelay:1];
        } else if (recognizer.view == _twoStone
               && recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
            _oneStone.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            _twoStone = recognizer.view;
            [self moveTwo:CGPointMake(-1, 0) withView:_twoStone];
            self.move2++;
            [self performSelector:@selector(causeADelay:) withObject:_oneStone afterDelay:1];
        }
        self.moveCount++;
```

}

One of the things I tried was creating a delay on when I can interact with my `UIView` objects.  This worked ONLY IF I waited a split half-second to interact.  The full delay would occur, and everything would work.

My bug is when you swipe them both at the same time.  Is that because of the swipe gestures attached to them?

I also tried removing and reapplying the objects as subviews...didn't work, obviously.  I really need this to work otherwise I have a dead-end game.  I was very new to coding when I first started and never thought about Cocos2d or other game-driven platforms for development, so everything I have came from on-the-fly thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions, but here's a particularly easy one:

Remove the swipe gesture recognizers from the stones and attach them instead to the common superview of the stones. This solves the problem, because only one gesture recognizer *on the same view* will recognize at any one time.

Of course, you will now have to use hit-testing to find out which stone (if any) is being swiped. But that's an easy implementation detail, and is a small price to pay.

And of course another cool feature is that you now only need four gesture recognizers total!

Comment: Will that conflict with the point of the game?  Each stone is 1x1 (The size of a square on the 5x5 grid).  If the entire 5x5 grid contains the swipe gesture recognizers, does that prevent the individual stones from being interacted with?  Or can I still rely on touching one of the stones and make it look like it was that particular stone that received the touch?  thanks

Comment: The _user_ doesn't know who is _detecting_ the touch. To the user, it will appear that he's shoving stones around. Everything will work exactly the same way except for who is _detecting_ the touch. Do you see?

Comment: hit-testing sounds great, can't wait to look it up.  Absolutely a small price to pay (without even knowing what it is yet).  Thanks a blank-ton!

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_hit_testing and I actually give an example of this very thing, i.e. putting a gesture recognizer on the common superview of a some views.

Comment: Looks great, going to plug away now.  Since I have you here, thanks for writing the books you've written!  I used your fundamentals book on iOS 7 and its companion to teach myself everything about coding for iOS.  I've got about 2-3 weeks left before I launch my app (having started in January), and yea, if it wasn't for you we wouldn't be having this conversation. cheers